# Citizen Patrol Badge wasn't rescinded when the flag was retracted - shouldn't it be?

Tags: support, badges, flagging-badges

Not sure if this is the intended behavior of the badge system.

Reproduction steps:

1. Flag a question (eg: duplicate)
2. Get awarded Citizen Patrol
3. Retract the flag

Expected result:

1. Badge rescinded

Actual result:

1. Badge is not rescinded

Comment: See also the general FAQ on badges, [How do "badges" work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17853/how-do-badges-work), section *Can badges be lost/revoked/taken away after they are awarded? If so, how and when?*. As that section says, regular (non-tag) badges aren't generally revoked once awarded.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Per the [FAQ on Badges](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/188732/622284), the only criteria to earn this badge is that you flag a post:

> #### Citizen Patrol
>
> - bronze; awarded once
> - Flag a post

It [doesn't matter if the flag is acted upon by a moderator](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/131337/622284) or retracted by the user (as you observed). You still performed the one and only requirement to be awarded the badge: flagging a post.

As to why it wasn't rescinded when you retracted it - the system generally never removes badges, even if the triggers for them are no longer there. Once you qualify for the badge *and are awarded it*, you keep it. The point of the Citizen Patrol badge is that you are aware that flagging is possible, so using the tool, whether you retract or not, is the important thing.

Comment: marked as answer, because it is.  but, the more subtle question ... is this the place to report bugs, if someone (thinks) they may have found one?

Comment: Yep! animuson, a staff member, retagged your question to remove the [bug] tag as the answer to your question was borne of a misunderstanding, not a flaw in the site (which is totally fine by the way!) Any bugs that affect the whole network are on-topic here. If it only affects a particular site, then that site's meta site is the place to ask! @undrline-ReinstateMonica